# Django file system

Tags: python, django, filesystems

I have a web app which I am creating for screen writers. I need to have a filesystem so that the users can see which files they recently created. They also will have the option to create a new file which they will be able to edit and save online. I was wondering if anybody knows of a django app, that allows user to create and edit files.

Comment: You mean something like google docs?

Comment: exactly like google docs, where the user has the ability to see files they cerated and they can create a new file

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opengoo/ - Open-source version of FengOffice, but it's not django (and there is not a similar one implemented in django AFAIK).

Comment: @birryree thanks for the link, however I already created the editor in django, I just need a way for the users to create a next file which will be stored on the server which they can later retrieve and edit

Comment: If you already have the editor, then you already have the front end to creating a text file. When they 'save' the file, you could save it to the server's file system, or into a database. Or maybe I'm not clear on what exactly you're asking for, if you already have an editor.

Comment: @birryree Would it be better to save the contents of the iframe to the database, or would it be better to have a file living on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [the normal file mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield). Django's file fields are storage-independent, and will save them to disk, WebDAV, S3, etc. as configured.